# Why is my workspace window empty (while I can see my variables with "whos")?

Tags: matlab, workspace

So I am having this problem for a few days now. 
I am using Matlab R2017b on Mac, and it worked perfectly up untill a few days ago when I ran a code (not for the first time) and my variables did not appear in the workspace window. However I can see them all when using the command "whos".

I was running very simple scripts to create graphs and perform stats.

I have no idea if it is related, I wouldn't think so but just in case, it happened when I ran the code and also got that warning:

> "Cleaning up unclosed ZipFile for archive
>   /Users/.../CD_EBCC_data.xlsx"

I've rebooted the computer but no changes.

Thanks in advance for your help! Let me know if any extra info could be of help.

EDIT:

Here a screenshot:
[image]
on the left are all my variables as visualized with "whos", on the right you can see the empty workspace.
If I type "a=1" in the command window, there is no variable *a* created in the workspace but if I type whos I can see it is actually there. It is just that I cannot see it in the workspace window. If I type the name of an existing variable, it is displayed normaly in the command window. Hope that is clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by "my variables did not appear in the workspace"? What happens if you type the name of a variable in the command window?

Comment: About what caused it I really have no clue. There was no clear reason one variables stoped being displayed in the workspace window. Except that I run a script, that I had already launched previously without problems and that I got the warning I mentionned above.

Comment: I’ve always closed the workspace window, so obviously have never ran into something like this. But it looks like a bug, which you should report to the MathWorks.

Comment: I had some times this kind of bug in ubuntu, generally when I am quite in the limit of RAM usage, but if I reboot MATLAB it generally goes

Comment: I will fill a report to MathWorks then and get used to work without the window for now!